# Prony method for calculating quasi normal mode of a black hole from time domain data

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

Prony method is a method for calculating the quasi normal mode from time domain data. It is bades in the solution of a linear system as described [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0701086). What I do not understand is how many damped exponenets of the form:

$$\Phi(t)=\sum_{j=1}^pC_j \, \exp(-i \omega_j t)$$

should be present in the summation, from my trials I have seen that the result depends greatly on this number, so are there any guidelines?

Comment: Why is that damped? Does $\omega_j$ have a negative imaginary part?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes generally $\omega$  are complex number with negative immaginary part.

Comment: Doesn’t the hole actually have an infinite number of quasinormal modes? Doesn’t the number of terms to use just depend on the accuracy you want?

Answer (score 0):

A black hole (or alternative compact object) has infinitely many quasi normal modes (QNMs), all of which generically get some level of excitation. So from a physical point of view, you should include infinitely many terms.

However, in practice this neither feasible nor desirable. First of all one should note that we are dealing with exponentially decaying modes. Consequently, if you wait for a bit the signal will be completely dominated by the slowest decaying mode. Moreover, your signal will typically contain noise and possibly subdominant features that are not well modeled by a decaying exponential (e.g. power law tails). Consequently, using too many modes will lead to over fitting of the signal, and unreliable results.

How many modes to use in practice will depend on the quality of the signal, the nature of the signal, and your goal with the extraction. There is no easy answer here, and you will have to experiment to find what number works for you. Varying the number of terms used should give an indication of the size of the error that you are making.